# Is my Type D Spain visa valid for travel to Bulgaria and Macedonia?

Tags: visas, spain

I'm quite confused with my Visa. I was able to travel recently to EU countries such as Czech Republic, Hungary, Austria, Germany, and Italy. However I am not so sure if I could enter Bulgaria or Macedonia. I saw some sites saying that one could enter these countries with a Schengen visa. I'm not sure if my Visa is a Schengen visa since it says it's valid for SPAIN unlike my previous Schengen tourist visa from France that said ETATS SCHENGEN.

Comment: You will need another visa for Bulgaria as Bulgaria is not part of the Schengen

Comment: @user69348: Despite not being a full member of Schengen, Bulgaria does allow holders of certain Schengen visas to enter without a visa for Bulgaria.

Comment: [Bulgaria's website](https://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html) says that Schengen visa holders can be admitted for 90 days, but [Timatic says](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&DE=SOF&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) (I picked an arbitrary nationality that requires visas) the exemption only applies to Schengen C visa holders, which would mean the OP needs a Bulgarian visa, I think, but the information is a bit contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your visa type - it is not very clear from your question which visa you have. There are 3 types of Schengen visas:

1. **Uniform Schengen Visas (USV)** - this is what most of the tourists receive, multiple visits / short term. Valid for all Schengen countries.
2. **National Visas ("D" category/type)** - long term visas (study/work etc.) also enables you to visit all Schengen countries.
3. **Limited territorial validity visas (LTV)** - this one valid only in country specified in visa, so you can't visit other countries using it.

If you traveled using your visa in different EU countries already it should be type 1 or 2, but if you are saying "valid only for Spain" it can be also type 3, though I'm not sure how you could travel with this one to other EU countries (e.g. Germany or Czech Republic).

See more details on Schengen visa types [here](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/).

Comment: This answer is not really on point, because Bulgaria and Macedonia are not Schengen countries. Bulgaria allows holders of certain Schengen visas to enter nevertheless. Macedonia unilaterally follows a similar policy, but it is not clear whether it extends to category D visas.

Comment: There were EU countries mentioned in the question, and in any case without knowledge of visa type and also national passport which one have it is difficult to guess which countries are covered by visa and which are visa-free based on national passport for example

Comment: The question title makes it quite clear that the visa in question is type D. Romania uses Schengen's list of visa-exempt nationalities, and Macedonia's own list is almost identical, so I think it can be safely assumed that the OP is not visa exempt for either country.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Didn't read question title carefully enough :)